# How to install java enviroment on Windows 8?

Tags: java, windows-8-preview, runtime

I want to try the newest Windows 8 64-bit. I installed it successfully. I tried to install one trading application called Interactive Brokers Trading Station which requires at least `jre-1.4`.

I went to the Oracle website to download the latest release. I tried `1.6` and even `1.7`, however it seems Windows 8 could not link the environment to the software, whichs keep complaining about the absence of Java.

I tried to change the compatibility settings of the executable, which didn't do anything. Can you give me any hints?

Comment: Interesting quote I found in passing -- "Certainly, the Windows 8 Developer Preview has no Java support (and some Java desktop apps that work fine in Windows 7 simply don’t load, even with Java installed)." - The source isn't anyone specifically in-the-know, but I think it sums up what you're also experiencing.  You may just be out of luck until Windows 8 is beyond a Preview (and/or Oracle updates Java to support it). ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if the path variable helps to solve your problem

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/install-windows.html

Comment: That's about installing the Java 2 SDK, not the JRE?

Comment: Sorry. It seems not working. I do not wanna develop anything. I just want to set up the java re. I try to load a java online applet on ie. Failed as well with complaints that no java.

Comment: no problem, on that link did you see the point no 5 about configuring your path variable after installation, also those comments are typically the same for any version and not just for 1.4. Good luck!

Comment: I found the answer. You have to install both java 32 and 64bit since lot of application simply based on 32bit as default without 64bit version. Thanks two people above.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out you have to install both java 32 and 64 bit since lot of application simply base on 32bit as default without 64bit version.

Comment: I really need to stress that this answer and the one above are BOTH correct answers (This one is more correct). A lot of software looks for "java" so it needs the system path, but for users this is frustrating. If you installed a 64 bit JDK you're probably going to see a lot of failures. You need to install both for programs that don't have intelligent pathfinding (iReport from JasperReports for instance). A simple install of the STANDARD JRE as well as the JDK is needed.

Answer (score 1):

win8 IE 10. IE runs 64 bit but the tabs are 32 by default so against intuition you have to download and install 32 bit JRE. To install the 64 bit JRE you have to enable protected mode, but that breaks lots of other stuff and still doesn't actually run 64 bit java :(

Comment: There should be no reason it wouldn't run Java.  The 64-bit IE process supports add-ons.  If Java doesn't work its because Oracle has not added supported for IEx64.

Answer (score 0):

Installing both 32 & 64 bit did not help me at all, I still getting general exception errors. I am guessing we need to wait for official support for Windows 8 in 7 build 10 I think if I am not mistaken.