# Windows 8 & Java Development

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-8, jdk

I'm considering to upgrade my PC to Windows 8, but I have one concern though.

I haven't yet found any "confirmation", that the JDK and Eclipse will work on Windows 8.

Have anyone tried to develop/run Java-applications on Windows 8?

Comment: I think you could get a development partition and try installing Win 8 and eclipse on it. I don't see any reason you will run into a problem. since Win 8 is based on the Win 7 design.

Comment: If nobody answers, you could easily try this in a virtual machine install of Windows 8. My guess however would be that "legacy" desktop apps will be compatible between Win7 and Win8.

Comment: You can do better -- look for experience of somebody else. At least jdk is 'working' under windows 8. See link http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2012/01/install-jdk-7-on-windows-8.html

Comment: Tiny anecdotal experience: at least one of my colleagues uses Windows 8 as his primary development platform just fine (using Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: JDK 6 update 30-ish works for me in Windows 8 in a Parallels VM on mac OSX.

Comment: With Windows8 and Eclipse Juno I have more issues. First of all, when I switch between JSP page and Java code page I have a black screen for 1 second. No other issues, but this for me is very annoying.

Comment: I did the Win8 upgrade and it backed up my old windows directory and all my previously installed programs worked just fine and all items in program menu were retained.    After install, i recommend installing a program called "Soluto".

Answer (score 11):

Confirmed - the JDK and Eclipse will work on Windows 8.  I'm running Windows 8 RTM (64-bit).  I just downloaded Eclipse from http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junor and the JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u31-download-1501634.html.  I'm not a Java developer, but I was able to open Eclipse and build and run a simple Hello World app.

Answer (score 1):

Running Java in Windows 8 shall probably not be a problem, because Java is a portable and cross-platform language. Dependency issues are not non-existent, but they are minimized and isolated (if they exist) at a (usually low) layer of the code, and hidden from the user / API client. So if your code has a portability issue it will generally be an issue and not Windows 8-specific. (e.g. if your code breaks ported from Win8 to another OS, it is not Win8's fault)

So generally if java and javac run in Windows 8, all Java programs shall run in Windows 8 as far as no dependency issues arise. Installing in a partition as pointed out or running on a virtual machine Windows 8 can be a way to confirm yourself how much is possible to accomplish in this environment.

I would suggest checking out some of the other sites of the network, namely superuser [may have an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/356034/how-to-install-java-enviroment-on-windows-8)...

Comment: This answer doesn't really contain any factual information - Java being portable only refers to the different platform variants being compatible with one another, it's not a guarantee that any given port won't ever break because of changes to the underlying API which are outside of then JDK's control. (No information except for the link to SuperUser which should arguably have been a comment on the question - if not for that this would've been a downvote.)

Comment: I'm also bothered by the scare quotes. Java *is* obviously portable and cross platform because it has, in fact, been ported to different platforms.

Comment: I agree it has been ported to many platforms but you highlighted that there are API dependencies which is my point in quoting it in order to say that portability issues are not non-existent! I also suppose that if you are not working on a very high level kind of thing with too many dependencies on Windows 8 you can have everything running quite smoothly. If you have any dependency on the OS it is as much a problem as it would have been moving it from windows to Linux.

Comment: That's just arguing semantics. *Portable* simply does not mean "porting issues are non-existent", just that it's at all feasible to create compatible ports. (Which, in Java's case, it is.) All it means is that platform dependencies are isolated at a (usually low) layer of the code, and hidden from the user / API client. By your definition, every single piece of portable code on Earth would be merely "portable".

Comment: You know what, you are right, I shall correct this and explain that dependencies can be an issue! Thanks for the advice! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have installed windows 8,
tried to install Juno-> comparability issue was there
but Helios seems to have no problem. But some plugins are not working in Helios.(ADT plugin for Android development).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse Kepler 4.1.2 on a Windows 8 tablet, everything is working fine.

My settings are: RAM 512 vheap: 32 internal storage 200, no sdcard.

Had some problems with using tablet size avds, but fixed the issue by copying my Windows 7 avd settings for using arm. I also resolved issues with graphics by enabling the host gpu.

Still have graphics issues with avds running 3.2 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

JDK 1.7_10 **or newer** is **almost** supported under Windows 8.. 
which fortunately means my company cannot upgrade my Win7 machine.. yes!

taken form here: http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/win8_faq.xml

> Windows 8 is officially supported with the release of Java 7 Update
>   10. **Java will only be supported in Desktop screen**. Java will not run in the Start screen.